# class file for java.util.Map not found

Tags: java, java-me, j2mepolish

I got this error

```
class file for java.util.Map not found
```

on this line of code:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

I am developing a J2ME project with J2ME polish 2.4, using the json-1.0.jar library. The project was working not until I updated J2ME polish from 2.3 to 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know J2ME Does not support java.util.Map so Json lib that you are using internally using java.util.Map so you should use json library for J2ME.